# Returning a getter, defined on an object literal?

Tags: javascript

Please take a look at how function Y "reuses" function X's itemCount getter. I thought I should be able to define it as **itemCount: x.ItemCount**, but that doesn't work.

Question: Can someone explain why I have to do the below to return X's itemCount from Y? There must be something that makes get special from a normal function.

```
// Returns simple object literal with 2 properties.
function X () {
    return {
        items: {
            1: {},
            2: {}
        },
        get itemCount () {
            return Object.keys(this.items).length;
        }
    }
}

// Returns a simple object literal with the same 2 properties as its "x" arg.
function Y (x) {
    return {
        items: x.items,
        get itemCount () {
            return x.itemCount;
        }
    };
}

var x = new X();
var y = new Y(x);
y.itemCount; // returns 2
```

Comment: perhaps retains the reference to `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a function instead of a getter you would have to bind the value of `this`.

For example like this:

```
function X () {
    return {
        items: {
            1: {},
            2: {}
        },
        itemCount: function() {
            return Object.keys(this.items).length;
        }
    }
}

function Y (x) {
    return {
        items: x.items,
        itemCount: x.itemCount.bind(x)
    };
}
```

When you call `x.itemCount()` the value of `this` is in the context of `x` however if you call `y.itemCount()` (`y` being the object created from `Y(x)`) `this` will be in the context of `y`.

In order to get around this you need to bind the `this` variable using `bind()`.

Comment: You got it, Ryan. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're running the code `return x.itemCount`. It is expected, therefore, that value returned by that `return` statement is the computed value of the `itemCount` property on `x` -- what else could `x.itemCount` possibly be?

If you want to run the code of the `itemCount` getter on a different object, the best course is to extract out the item-counting code into a separate function that is used by the getter:

```
function itemCounter(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj.items).length
}
```

Then each `itemCount` getter can `return itemCounter(this)`.

If you don't have the ability to modify `x`, you can inelegantly extract the getter and `call` it with the `this` of `y`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, "itemCount").get.call(this)
```